# Application.Mod() Throwing Run-time error '438'

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a Run-error '438' when trying to execute an Excel Mod function within my VBA macro.  Here's the code:

```
Dim tempVarInt As Integer
Dim replaceCards As Integer
' code
tempVarInt = ActiveSheet.Mod(replaceCards, 100)
```

I've tried all variations: `Application.Mod`; `Application.ActiveSheet.Mod`; `Application.WorkSheet.Mod`.  All throw the '438' error.  When I looked through others' questions about this error, there were some references to Excel functions that are not supported - could `Mod` be one of those?  If so, how can I get the modulus of the number?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
tempVarInt = replaceCards Mod 100
```